# Prevent form being submitted until final button - avoid edit page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I know there are a lot of similar questions on SO but I haven't found one that fits what I'm trying to do...(because I'm not 100% sure it is even possible to do what I am trying to do!!)

At the moment I have a page that creates several form_tags based on how many 'questions' there are in the 'test', like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <% @test.questions.each do |question| %>
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Question <%= question.question %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p>
        <%= image_tag question.image.url(:medium) %>
      </p>
      <%= form_tag edit_test_testsession_path(@test, question.testsessions), id: 'submit_answer' do %>
        <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "A" %> A
        <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "B" %> B
        <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "C" %> C
        <%= radio_button_tag :answer, "D" %> D
        <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: "btn btn-success", id: 'single_submit' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
  <%= link_to "See Test Results!", results_path(@test), class: "btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block", id: "submit_all" %>
</div>
```

At the moment I have disabled the 'submit' buttons because I don't want the forms to actually be submitted until all of them are completed so I have this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn.btn-success').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value="Resubmit";
  });

  $('#submit_all').click(function(){
    $('#submit_answer').each(function(){
      $(this).submit();
    });
  });
});
```

It does attempt to submit the answers but still tries to take the user to an edit page, but of several [:id], which obviously doesn't work...

In my TestsessionsController I have this:

```
class TestsessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @testsession = Testsession.new
    redirect_to action: :create
  end

  def create
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @test.questions.each do |question|
      @test.testsessions.create user: current_user, question: question
    end
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def index
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @questions = @test.questions
    # @testsession = Testsession.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @testsession = Testsession.find(params[:id])
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
    @questions = @test.questions
  end

  def update
    @testsession = Testsession.find(params[:id])
    # @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @testsession.update(params.require(:testsession).permit(:answer))
    redirect_to action: :results
  end

  def edit
    @testsession = Testsession.find(params[:id])
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @testsession.update(params.require(:testsession).permit(:answer))
    redirect_to action: :results
  end

  def results
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    @testsession = Testsession.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Is there any way to force the last link to take it directly to the results page, but still submit the information from the form_tags?

At the moment it is just giving me this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/tests/1/testsessions/%23%3CTestsession::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fe197a72e40%3E/edit"
```

and only when I hit the back button it takes me to the results page...

**EDIT**

config/routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'welcome#index'

  get 'tests/:id/testsessions/new' => 'testsessions#create'

  get 'tests/:id/testsessions/results' => 'testsessions#results', as: :results

  resources :tests do
    resources :questions
    resources :testsessions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Upd** I think what you was meaning is:

```
 <%= form_tag edit_test_testsession_path(@test, @testsession), id: 'submit_answer' do %>
```

---

The problem seems to be here:

```
 <%= form_tag edit_test_testsession_path(@test, question.testsessions), id: 'submit_answer' do %>
```

You are passing a collection of all associated testsessions instead of single object, and I doubt it's what you intended to do.

Please show a part of your config/routes.rb related to the controller

Comment: I've added the config/routes file...I see that it is returning a collection of objects but that is because it is *meant* to be iterating over the questions and submitting several answers....